# Render styled google map

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I can't figure out how to create a styled map so I can use my array of styles. I'm using the Advanced custom fields plugin so the user can enter their own locations, so I used the jQuery from the documentation to render the map. The code is below:

```
// My Styles!

var styles = [
{
featureType: "administrative",
elementType: "all",
stylers: [
  { saturation: -100, }
]
}];

function render_map( $el ) {

// var
var $markers = $el.find('.marker');

// vars
var args = {
    zoom        : 10,
    center      : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    mapTypeId   : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    scrollwheel: false
};

// create map               
var map = new google.maps.Map( $el[0], args);

// add a markers reference
map.markers = [];

// add markers
$markers.each(function(){

    add_marker( $(this), map );

});

// center map
center_map( map );

}
```

I usually use this to create a styled map but I can't get it to work with the above code:

```
var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
{name: "Styled Map"});
```

I realise this is probably simple! Although I like to learn why things work and why they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling?hl=fr) (section Creating a StyledMapType), it seems you forgot a part of the code :

```
  // Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
  map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
  map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
```

You declare a new `StyledMap` but never tell to your current Google Maps instance it must use it.

If you don't want to switch between many different StyledMap, you can also set style with :

```
map.setOptions({styles: styles}); // map is your current map object
```

With this second approach, this piece of code become obsolete :

```
var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles,
{name: "Styled Map"});
```

I have never use `StyledMap` in GoogleMaps and my answer is based on my other knowledges of Google Maps API and the documentation. So it can be incorrect.

Comment: Cheers buddy! `map.setOptions({styles: styles});` is what I needed.